# Impala/SQL: group by - aggregate a field by creating a list of all values

Tags: sql, group-by, impala

I have a table below:

```
id  |  animal  |  team
-------------------------
 1  |  dog     |  A
 2  |  cat     |  A
 3  |  cow     |  A
 4  |  bird    |  B
 5  |  rat     |  B
 6  |  goat    |  C
```

I want to group by team, and aggregate the animals in a team to a list. i.e. the output should look like:

```
team  |  animal_list
--------------------------
 A    | [dog, cat, cow]
 B    | [bird, rat]
 C    | [goat]
```

Can this be achieved by Impala/SQL query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use this query.

```
select team, concat("[", group_concat(animal), "]") as animal_list from   anmials group by team
```

You can see the result output here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b03f/3

Comment: Thanks! But I am wondering if it is possible to just keep one copy of each values in the list? For example, if a team has two cats, I want [dog, cat, cow] instead of [dog,cat,cat,cow]?

Comment: yes, you can do that, use like this select team, group_contact(distinct(animal)) as animal_list from anmials group by team

Comment: order by is not handled in the impala version of group_concat, are you aware of any workaround?